# php frameworks - do I use a component?

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, yii

I am using Yii framework, (had a similar problem in CakePHP before) in that I want to create a parser for HTML pages. There will be a few different pages that will need to be scraped and parsed so I was thinking of using a design pattern to do this, possibly "strategy pattern".

But my question is, where do I add this functionality to Yii? It's not a model or controller? I will be creating a few classes most likely, for parsing different pages. So is this where I create a component? Or is there somewhere else in Yii that I can add this code and use it from the controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in Yii2 framework  creating a componet exenteding the Component class

```
namespace app\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;

class MyComponent extends Component
{
    public function test()
    {
    echo "Test Component ";
    }

}
```

add you component in config main.php

Add your component inside the config/web.php file

eg:

```
'components' => [

     'mycomponent' => [

        'class' => 'app\components\MyComponent',

        ],
       ]
   .......
```

And the you can relate to you component in controller

```
namespace app\controllers;
use Yii;

class TestController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
   public function actionTest()
   {
      Yii::$app->mycomponent->Test();
    }

}
```

You can refer to this [doc of Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-application-components.html) and/or [this sample..](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0/)